# How to parse a json file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, parsing, fetch

I got a little problem with the nodejs fetch module and more particularly with the JSON parse. When I want to parse the stock variable, he tells me that the size is equal to 0 ? But my file is not empty and the path is good.
The code is really simple but I don't know why this error append and I spend too much time on this.
Someone know why I get this error and how I can resolve it ?

here the code of my js file :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const keyword='test';

const url='http://localhost:8888/test.json';

   fetch(url).then((stock) => {
    console.log(stock);
    const jsonFile = JSON.parse(stock);
    const newCategory = jsonFile[test];
    console.log(newCategory);
   }).catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

And the error in my terminal with the first console.log() :

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object] },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'http://localhost:8888/test.json',
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
     counter: 0 } }
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fetch.then (/Users/me/Desktop/test_json/index.js:11:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api returns a [Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) object

you can call [Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Using async/await:

```js
const body = await fetch(url);
const json = await body.json();
console.log(json);
```

Using promises:

```js
fetch(url).then((stock) => {
    return stock.json()
}).then(json => {
    console.log(json);
});
```

JSON.parse:

```js
fetch(url).then((stock) => {
    return stock.text()
}).then(text => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(text));
});
```

Comment: perfect, with promises I can see my json file ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the body in json parse like bellow,

JSON.parse(stock.text())

Or you can directly use json data without parsing just using stock.json() function